# Intuition for the differences between characteristic and minimal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I understand the definitions of the characteristic and minimal polynomials, but I don't quite see an easy way to explicitly come up with examples of matrices for which the two polynomials satisfy some properties.

For example, consider the following three exercises from Sheldon Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right*, chapter 8C:

> 4. Give an example of an operator on $\mathbb{C}^4$ whose characteristic polynomial equals $(z-1)(z-5)^3$ and whose minimal polynomial equals $(z-1)(z-5)^2$.
> 5. Give an example of an operator on $\mathbb{C}^4$ whose characteristic and minimal polynomials both equal $z(z-1)^2(z-3)$.
> 6. Give an example of an operator on $\mathbb{C}^4$ whose characteristic polynomial equals $z(z-1)^2(z-3)$ and whose minimal polynomial equals $z(z-1)(z-3)$.

For Exercise 6, it is obvious that we just take a diagonal matrix with diagonal $0,1,1,3$. However, I don't quite see how to come up with examples of operators in questions 4 and 5 - I don't have any intuition between how the structure of an operator/matrix relates to its characteristic and minimal polynomials.

Can someone please explain the reasoning one can use to find answers to the questions?

From a quick search I understand that Jordan forms of matrices could be useful in finding explicit forms of matrices satisfying these properties, but these exercises are actually before the introduction of Jordan forms in the book so I would appreciate not using them in the answers. Thank you.

Comment: What are the characteristic and minimal polynomial of the identity matrix $n \times n$ ?

Comment: @reuns The minimal polynomial of a diagonal matrix will have no repeating zeros, and it's the minimal polynomials with repeated zeros where I'm struggling to come up with intuitive examples.

Comment: What are those polynomials exactly ?

Comment: @reuns $(z-n)^n$ and $(z-n)$, respectively.

Comment: Not exactly. What is the obvious (non-zero) polynomial $P(x)=\sum_{k=0}^d a_k x^k$ such that $P(I_n) = \sum_{k=0}^d a_k (I_n)^k= 0$ ?

Comment: @reuns Sorry, I meant to say $(z-1)^n$ and $(z-1)$ of course.

Comment: Ok now what about $3 I_n$ ? And what about the $n\times n$ matrix $M = \text{diag}(3,1,\ldots)$ (ie. the identity matrix with the first entry replaced by $3$)

Comment: I just used mathematica to find some example. I was not particularly interested in these exercises (the exercises based on mechanical calculations doesnt like me very much). Once you have some example of such a matrix it is easy to change something to get an example with a different result.

Comment: @reuns This is the reasoning I took in Ex. 6 - to note that the matrix $diag(a,b,c,d)$ will have a characteristic polynomial $(z-a)(z-b)(z-c)(z-d)$, and the minimal polynomial will be the same but without repeated roots. I still don't quite see how it helps with the other cases.

Comment: Then what is the characteristic and minimal polynomial of $\scriptstyle \begin{pmatrix} 0 & a \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$  and $\scriptstyle \begin{pmatrix} 1 & a \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$  ?

Comment: @reuns Right, I have noticed "by inspection" that I can get the behavior that I want by adding ones on the superdiagonal. Is there any general intuition behind this, or is it like Masacroso says and it's mostly just being familiar with examples?

Comment: You didn't answer to my last comment. $\scriptstyle \begin{pmatrix} 0 & a \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ is **nilpotent** ie. its minimal polynomial is of the form $x^k = 0$. Also minimal and characteristic polynomial behave well under $M \mapsto M+b I$ and under (diagonal) concatenation of matrices. This leads directly to the idea of the (complex) Jordan normal form.

Comment: @Ali I find it's easiest to think of this in terms of Jordan form.  Happily, Jordan form provides a way to understand what *any* operator does up to similarity, so in a sense, we can describe all operators efficiently.  Another way to go is to use rational canonical form, which works well for this particular problem.

Comment: @reuns and Omnomnomnom: Okay, I think I understand now why these exercises are *before* the introduction of the Jordan form in the book... I'll go ahead and read about that to get the intuition that I want. Thanks.

Comment: @Ali I think it's fair to say that there isn't supposed to be an intuitive approach until you've looked into Jordan form.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a possible way of grasping the difference between characteristic and minimal polynomial in an **algebraic-intuitive** way (no Jordan form, no invariant spaces, no generalised eigenvectors etc.). 
To do this you need some **prerequisites**:

- You already know that the elements on the main diagonal of an upper triangular matrix are the eigenvalues of the matrix and the determinant of this matrix is the product of these eigenvalues. For example
  $$
  A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & \star & \star \\ 
  0 & 3 & \star \\  
  0 & 0 & 4 
  \end{pmatrix} \rightarrow det(A) = 2\cdot3\cdot4
  $$
- You already know that the powers of upper triangular matrices with only zeros on the main diagonal will "finally vanish" (this property is called "nilpotent"). For example
  $$
  A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
  0 & 0 & 1 \\  
  0 & 0 & 0 
  \end{pmatrix} \rightarrow 
  A^2 =  \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
  0 & 0 & 0 \\  
  0 & 0 & 0 
  \end{pmatrix} \rightarrow
  A^3 =  \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
  0 & 0 & 0 \\  
  0 & 0 & 0 
  \end{pmatrix}
  $$
- You may already have noted that "diagonally" blocked matrices multiply "blockwise". For example:
  $$
  A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\   
  0 & 2 
  \end{pmatrix} \mbox{ and }
  B = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 0 & 0 \\   
  0 & 3 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 3
  \end{pmatrix} \rightarrow  
  C =  \begin{pmatrix} A & 0 \\ 
  0 & B 
  \end{pmatrix} = 
  \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
  0 & 2 & 0 & 0  & 0 \\
  0 & 0 &  3 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 &  0 & 3 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 &  0 & 0 & 3 \\
  \end{pmatrix}
  $$
  $$
  C^2 =  \begin{pmatrix} A^2 & 0 \\ 
  0 & B^2 
  \end{pmatrix} = 
  \begin{pmatrix} 4 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
  0 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 &  9 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 &  0 & 9 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 &  0 & 0 & 9 
  \end{pmatrix}
  $$

Now, you can construct your operators easily, that is, "blockwise". Let's take exercise 4 from above (let $I_3$ denote the identity matrix of dimension $3$):
$$(z-1)(z-5)^3 \mbox{ with minimal polynom }  (z-1)(z-5)^2$$
So, a possible operator may look like
$$A =\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 5 & \star & \star \\
0 & 0 &  5 & \star \\
0 & 0 &  0 & 5 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Let's call the bottom right matrix $B$. Since the minimal polynomial of $B$ is supposed to be $(z-5)^2$, you know that $B-5I_3$ needs to "vanish" when squared:
$$B-5I_3 =\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & \star & \star \\
0 &  0 & \star \\
0 &  0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} \mbox{ and } (B-5I_3)^2 = \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 &  0 & 0 \\
0 &  0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$$

From the above mentioned prerequisites you see that
$$B-5I_3 =\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 &  0 & 0 \\
0 &  0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} \mbox{ or } (B-5I_3) = \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 &  0 & 1 \\
0 &  0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} \mbox{ will do.}$$
Altogether:

$$A =\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 5 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 &  5 & 0 \\
0 & 0 &  0 & 5 
\end{pmatrix} \mbox{ or }
A =\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 5 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 &  5 & 1 \\
0 & 0 &  0 & 5 
\end{pmatrix}  \mbox{ or }A =\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 5 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 &  5 & 0 \\
0 & 0 &  0 & 5 
\end{pmatrix}
$$